# Function shows undefined even when the function is defined first

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have declared showData(), but still it shows undefined when the saveEdit() is called. I have called the showData() inside the saveEdit(), to display the local storage content in a table format after the local storage data is edited.  Being new to javascript, it makes it dificult to understand where the error is. As per my knowledge it the function is defined first, then it can be called in a function which is defined later.

```
class UserDetails{

  constructor()
  {
    this.arr = [];
    this.editIndex= null;
  }

  //delete the data from the local storage
  deleteData(index) {
    this.arr.splice(parseInt(index), 1);
    let value = JSON.stringify(this.arr);
    localStorage.setItem("localData", value); 
    let td = event.target.parentNode; 
    let tr = td.parentNode;
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  }

  //get data from local storage and display the local storage data on the screen
  showData() {
    let tbl = document.getElementById("tableDisplay");
    let str = localStorage.getItem("localData");
    let x = tbl.rows.length;

    while(--x){
      tbl.deleteRow(x);
    }
    //checking whether the local storage is not empty
    if (str != null) {
      this.arr = JSON.parse(str);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
        let r = tbl.insertRow();
        r.innerHTML=`
          <td>${this.arr[i].fName}</td>
          <td>${this.arr[i].lName}</td>
          <td>${this.arr[i].age}</td>
          <td>${this.arr[i].email}</td>
          <td>${this.arr[i].number}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="test.editData(${i});"> Edit </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="test.deleteData(${i});"> Delete </button>
          </td>`;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("fName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("lName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("age").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("number").value = "";
    document.getElementById("saveBtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("addBtn").style.display = "block";
  }

  //empty the local storage
  deleteLocalStorageData() {
    localStorage.clear();
    document.getElementById("tableDisplay").innerHTML = "All Data Deleted!";
  }

  //edit the data in the local storage
  editData(index) {
    this.editIndex = index;
    document.getElementById("fName").value = this.arr[index].fName;
    document.getElementById("lName").value = this.arr[index].lName;
    document.getElementById("age").value = this.arr[index].age;
    document.getElementById("email").value = this.arr[index].email;
    document.getElementById("number").value = this.arr[index].number;
    document.getElementById("addBtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("saveBtn").style.display = "block";
  }

  saveEdit() {

    this.arr[this.editIndex] = {
      fName: document.getElementById("fName").value,
      lName: document.getElementById("lName").value,
      age: document.getElementById("age").value,
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      number: document.getElementById("number").value
    };

    localStorage.setItem("localData", JSON.stringify(this.arr));
    showData();
  }

  //add data to local storage
  addData() {

    this.arr.push({
      fName: document.getElementById("fName").value,
      lName: document.getElementById("lName").value,
      age: document.getElementById("age").value,
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      number: document.getElementById("number").value
    });

    localStorage.setItem("localData", JSON.stringify(this.arr)); 

    let tr=document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML=`
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>${age}</td>
    <td>${email}</td>
    <td>${contact}</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="test.editData(${i});"> Edit </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="test.deleteData(${i});"> Delete </button>
    </td>`;

    document.getElementById("tableDisplay").appendChild(tr);

    document.getElementById("fName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("lName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("age").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("number").value = "";
    document.getElementById("saveBtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("addBtn").style.display = "block";

  }
}

let test = new UserDetails();
test.showData();
```

Comment: `this.showData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling methods of a `class` instance you should use the `this` keyword to refer to the instance.

```
this.showData()
```

Note that `class` is mostly a syntactic sugar for a `function`, and `class` methods are really just methods on the `class` (function) prototype.

This:

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod(){

  }
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for this:

```
function MyClass(){

}

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function(){

}
```

Comment: when the add function is called an error appears on the screen and disappears immediately in the console, hence unable to check the error